# Issues enabling handles in Edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

I'm a beginner in Blender and currently struggling on something that seems basic. I'm trying to move from the ''segment mode'' to the ''handle mode'' to edit the circle but can't seem to find any tutorial on how to do that.

The mode I actually have:

[image]

The mode i want to use:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the green icon on the edge of the R/H properties window to display the curve properties and then click the <kbd>Active Spline</kbd> dropdown to find the setting you need.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! It's working fine now :)

Comment: It's just a case of knowing where to look! :^)